# Setting Terms & Conditions in checkout

Tags: terms-and-conditions

I need to set 3 lots of Terms & Conditions for the customer to accept before placing their order, however, I have two customer groups: Retail and Wholesale. I only need 2 of the Terms and Conditions to display when Retail customers make a purchase and I need all 3 of the Terms and Conditions to display when a Wholesale customer makes a purchase.

Is there an easy way to do this if any? I have pretty basic knowledge of html and css so I'm guessing I would need a pretty detailed explanation if modifying magento file is required

Answer (score 0):

This is built in! All you have to do is enable it in `System > Configuration > Checkout`:

[image]

Comment: As mentioned by Digisha (great answer) you can also add more conditions from the Sales menu.

Answer (score 0):

This can be manage from admin `System > Configuration > Checkout > Checkout Options > Enable Terms and Conditions to Yes`
And you can add as many terms and conditions you need from `Sales > Terms and Conditions`

Comment: I have enabled the Terms and Conditions and they are displayed during checkout, but I want to isolate 1 of the 3 so it will only show and have to be accepted if a Wholesale customer makes a purchase, to the general public and Retail customers I only want 2 of the 3 T & C's to display

Comment: template for it is \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\agreements.phtml where you can identify you customer type assuming that customer is login.According to which you can display particular terms for particular customer type.

Comment: how would I go about writing the code to identify the customer type?

Comment: using below code you can check customer type from session-
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
{
   $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
   echo $customer->getGroupId();//Customer type id from Customer configuration
}